# Java libgdx 1.20 version texture bug

Tags: libgdx, textures

For 2 days I've been trying to fix bug with fickering and distored textures in my game. I was  serching on the internet and i tried a few solutions like using scene2d, but it didn't work. What should i do ?

This screenshot shows the problem: as the character moves, one eye is sometimes bigger than the other:

[image: Screenshot]

**edit:**

I still got the problem widthdistored eye when i use    sprite.setPosition((int) sprite.getX(), (int) sprite.getY()); every time before i render my character.

When i use custom viewport from the answer i see nothing on the game window what i do wrong?

```
package com.mygdx.redHoodie;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    public static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int GAME_HEIGHT= 480 ;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Background background;
    public Hoodie hoodie;

    public PixelMultipleViewport viewport;
       OrthographicCamera camera;
    public int gameMode; // 0 normalna gra, 1 level up, 2 end game

    public GameScreen(){
         camera= new OrthographicCamera(GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT);


         viewport = new PixelMultipleViewport(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, camera);
         viewport.update();
         camera.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        //klasy wyswietlane
        background= new Background(this);
        hoodie = new Hoodie(this);

        startNewGame();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu

         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);

         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
            batch.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);

         camera.update();
         //batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
         this.update(delta);
         this.batch.begin();
            toRender(delta);
         this.batch.end();



    }

    public void update(float delta){
        hoodie.update(delta);
    }

    public void toRender(float delta){
        background.render();
        hoodie.render();

    }

    public void startNewGame(){

    }
    public void startNevLevel(){

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewport.update(width, height,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Hard to figure without knowing how you loaded your textures. Can you provide the code for that? It's possible a bug was introduced, or you're using the textures in an unexpected way. From looking at the libgdx community forum, it doesn't seem like a common problem, because no one over there has complained of it.

Comment: I've got this bug when i do project same as in this tutorial http://theinvader360.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/street-race-swipe-libgdx-scene2d.html , but also when i copy paste solution from this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997013/sprite-flicker-while-moving-libgdx

Comment: Maybe you can describe in more detail what you mean by flickering and distorted, because those terms mean different things to different people. For instance, the other question you just linked seems to do with the sprite jerking from position to position, which is not what I would call flickering.

Comment: I' ve got character with small black rectangle eyes, in some cords of the viewport one eye was biger than the other eye. In 1.0 i don't have this problem.

Comment: This probably has to do with some combination of camera setup and texture filtering mode. If you show your code, maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YrvnhPif here is code, now i've just realized that when im using camera.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT); i get the same problem with eye on libgdx 1.0 but texture is still displaing without flickering.

Comment: now i've got this two problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918199/libgdx-distorted-texture-when-using-camera-settoorthofalse-game-width-game-he

Comment: Without screenshots, still hard to tell what's going on. Maybe your texture filter is set up to Nearest/Nearest, and the eye is bigger by only one pixel? When loading the texture, try setting it's filter to MipmapLinearNearest/Linear, and make sure you use a Texture constructor with the `useMipmaps` parameter and set that to true. The distortion is because you're using StretchViewport. I think you want to use FillViewport instead. Read up on Viewports here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: See my answer to your other question about viewports.

Comment: http://snag.gy/BOhID.jpg there is a screen of bad eye

Comment: http://snag.gy/Zgdjj.jpg there is pic of eye displayed in correc way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading your texture, use linear filtering and mip-mapping. The default filter is Nearest/Nearest, which will cause the issue you're seeing.

```
Texture myTexture = new Texture("textureFilename", true); //must enable mip-mapping in constructor
myTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

**EDIT:**

I realize now, looking at your screenshot, that you are doing pixelated graphics in a larger window. In order to do this, yes you need to keep the Nearest/Nearest filtering, instead of what I suggested.

To avoid having the some of the pixels vary in size, you must round off character movement and camera movement to the nearest world unit. When your character is partway between pixels, the size of the sprite pixels varies because they don't line up with the screen pixels.

You have your world scaled so one unit equals one of your large pixels. So whenever you draw anything, you need to first round its position to the nearest integer in the x and the y, as well as the camera position. So after you move the camera or the sprites, you must do something like this:

```
sprite.position.set((int)sprite.position.x,(int)sprite.position.y,sprite.position.z);
```

As far as your Viewport goes, if you don't want any black bars, you will probably need a custom Viewport class that tries to match your desired resolution as closely as possible and then extends it outwards to avoid distortion. ExtendViewport does something similar, but the difference with pixellated graphics is that you need the world resolution to be an integer multiple of the screen's resolution so the edges of pixels look crisp rather than fuzzy.

I think this will do what you want. It takes your desired screen resolution and shrinks it to fit where the size of each of your pixels in screen pixels is an integer. Then it extends the view beyond your desired resolution to avoid distortion and black bars. This class makes the assumption that all screen dimensions are always a multiple of 4. I *think* that's true. If you want to get fancy, you could use OpenGL scissoring to round down the viewport size to the nearest multiples of 4, to be safe. At most you would be having 2 pixels of black bar, which I don't think would be noticeable.

```
public class PixelMultipleViewport extends Viewport {

    private int minWorldWidth, minWorldHeight;

    public PixelMultipleViewport (int minWorldWidth, int minWorldHeight, Camera camera) {
        this.minWorldHeight = minWorldHeight;
        this.minWorldWidth = minWorldWidth;
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void update (int screenWidth, int screenHeight, boolean centerCamera) {

        viewportWidth = screenWidth;
        viewportHeight = screenHeight;

        int maxHorizontalMultiple = screenWidth / minWorldWidth;
        int maxVerticalMultiple = screenHeight / minWorldHeight;

        int pixelSize = Math.min(maxHorizontalMultiple, maxVerticalMultiple);

        worldWidth = (float)screenWidth/(float)pixelSize;
        worldHeight = (float)screenHeight/(float)pixelSize;

        super.update(screenWidth, screenHeight, centerCamera);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this texture filter is  better, but now eyes looks like behinnd the fog. http://snag.gy/2hBqV.jpg

Comment: I've just checked and i still got the same problem in a stretchet viewport.

Comment: When i use FitViewport is better. Is there anyway to don't have black bars and have no distored textures ?

Comment: OK, I see how to fix it... I'll change this answer.

Comment: i still got problem with distored pixel and when i use this wiev port i dont see just black screen on game window. see my question uptade.

Comment: The reason the eye is still distorted is that you are not using a camera viewport that is an integer multiple of the screen dimensions. Your window (from the latest screenshot) looks like it is 793x476, but you have scaled the scene to 800*480, so some pixels have to be rounded down to fit, so you end up with pixels of different sizes. And the reason you're getting a black screen with my Viewport is that you are putting in dimensions that are too big. I think in your case you want something like 210x160 for the minimum dimensions.

Comment: My Viewport takes your minimum screen size in asset pixels, and scales it up by the largest integer possible that will still fit in the window. But if you use dimensions that are larger than the window, then the largest integer multiple that will fit in the window is 0. But if you use 210x160 for example, and try to fit it into a window that is 800x480, then the biggest integer multiple that fits is 3. But since this would leave black borders on the sides, it will expand it to 266.6666667x160.

Comment: It doesn't wortk with     viewport = new PixelMultipleViewport(210, 160, camera); and     viewport = new PixelMultipleViewport(105, 80, camera);  Maybe its  foult of these settings :  camera.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
    batch.setTransformMatrix(camera.view); ?

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in my Viewport class. I just fixed it above.

Comment: Now hoodie looks fine thx a lot but every thing is too big, should iscale every thing by 0.5f ? What is a virtual width of viewport, 210 ?

Comment: I mean what cord have got top right corner ? And what should i do too keep my_character_width/screenWidth  = +/ const and similar to viewport 800 x 480 ?

Comment: I've assumed all along that your sprite assets were drawn pixel for pixel, but now it sounds to me like they are blown up. If you have a character that looks like it is 16 pixels tall, it should actually be 16 pixels tall in the source PNG file, not blown up to 48 or some multiple.

Comment: Your screenshots look like you intend for the scene to be 160 pixels tall (asset pixels, that is), so that's why I suggested 160 minimum height. As it looks like your game does not use box2d physics, a 1-to-1 pixel to world unit ratio makes the most sense, because you can just round off positions to nearest integer as my answer suggests.

Comment: As for keeping characterWidth/screenWidth constant for everything, that's impossible with pixelated graphics unless you have black bars. You can a least tweak the minWidth and minHeight values to get something that is roughly similar across all devices (scale your desktop window of the game up and down to get a feel for the range of sizes it's producing). If your game becomes unfair or something for virual viewports above a certain amount, you can introduce barriers in the game, or a fancier version of black bars where you put some kind of pattern sprite there instead of just showing black.

Comment: You mentioned Flappy Bird in one of you comments on your other question. That game actually does not do all this stuff correctly. It just follows my original suggestion of MipMap linear filtering, but I think it starts with upscaled graphics like you're using. On some devices, it has the "eye in fog" look to it all over the screen, just like you experienced when implementing my original suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different option I just came across. This is a way to draw your scene at the scale you like without black bars, at any resolution.

The visual quality will be slightly worse than in my other answer (where you draw at an integer multiple of your desired scene scale), but significantly better than using straight nearest filtering like in your screenshot.

The basic idea is to draw everything to a small FrameBuffer at the scale you want, and then draw the FrameBuffer's color texture to the screen using an upscaling shader that (unlike linear filtering) interpolates pixel colors only along the edges of sprite pixels.

The explanation [is here](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/612318). I have not ported this to Libgdx or tested it. And I'm not sure how well this shader would run on mobile. It involves running four dependent texture look-ups per screen fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old but as my search led me here, there may be more people following in the future. I was having the same pixel tearing issue, but only on my iOS 9 iPhone 4S. It was rendering fine on my Android 9 Pixel 2. Tried many things (especially rounding to full pixels) but even using an unzoomed fullscreen orthographic camera it suffered from the artefacts.

Forcing my texture to be POT (power of two) fixed the issue!